# how to update a single column of db without deleting its previous data?

Tags: php, mysql, database

i am updating a single column with many values using comma between them. they are working fine. but if update same column from other user the value inserted by previous users deleted. i want to keep values of previous user also with the insertion of new user value. and i also dont want to repeat the same value again because values i m using are unique ids..

```
            // update student list


$venue = ($_GET['venue']);
$district = ($_GET['dis']);
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
//print_r ($_POST);
 {
  @$std_list=implode(',',$_POST['std_list']);


    if(empty($std_list))
    {
        $error = 1;
        $get_value = "Please select you event students.";
    }

    else
    {

    //$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO events (std_list) 
//VALUES('".$std_list."')") or die(mysql_error());
    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE events SET std_list='".$std_list."' WHERE 
id='".$district."' ") or die(mysql_error());
    //echo "$msg";
    echo "Students list submitted successfully";
    }   
}
```

if any query you can ask again. values i am inserting are integers only. Same integer cant be used by two different users.

Comment: Dont use csv fields, use a `events_students` table

Comment: didnt get you ???? plz elaborate

Comment: Remove the `std_list` column in events table. Create a new table called `events_students`. When you want to add a new student to an event, you add a record to that table. Its standard database normalization and it exists to solve problems like this. Its also means you can perform queries like find all events a certain student is attending

Answer (score 0):

try this?

```
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE events SET std_list = CONCAT( std_list, '".$std_list."') WHERE 
id='".$district."' ") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: thanks this works but it  is inserting duplicate value also which is already in that column

Comment: what do u mean by duplicate value? hmm. the statement above will always take the values, append your values  and update the column with the new values. if you want to check on the duplicate value before updating the column, you will need to select the column and compare it using php.

Comment: i want to use comparrision in two places one is 1.   i am comparining this--> if($ctegoryy['id']==$user['std_list']) <-- but the values in $user['std_list'] are like 4,5,6 so comparission is not working   and the second one is    and this is update query -->$query = mysql_query("UPDATE events SET std_list=CONCAT( std_list, ',".$user['std_list']."') WHERE id='".$district."' ") or die(mysql_error()); <--